# Prevent from changing the page when there are form validation errors

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have few forms with several validation rules in a separated file named `form_validation.php`. One of them is an edit form that has the URL `/usuario/painel/editar` that receives the user `id` from the session, populating the form without the need to pass the `id` by `GET`, for security reasons.

The problem is that when I submit the form, the `action` is different, and when there are any errors, the URL changes to the `action`, making several errors to show when rendering the form, since the view is different and there are no `id` to receive.

```
<form action="/auto/usuario/edit/<?php echo $id_usuario; ?>" method="POST" id="editar_formulario_fisica_1" enctype="multipart/form-data">...</form>
```

For example: `localhost:8000/auto/usuario/edit/8`

Is there a way to refresh the same page and the same form, and show the errors? Or perhaps to prevent the URL from changing when there are errors?

Answer (score 0):

put the id in a hidden form field

```
echo form_hidden('userid',$id_usuario);
```

then get the user id in your controller or model

```
$userid = $this->input->post( 'userid') ;
```

edit ======

yes the URL can now be the same, because you are not adding the user id to the end of it. you don't need to because the user id is being passed in a hidden form field.

the form itself is in a view file. to show the form, you are first getting the user id, then you are calling/loading the form view file. in a similar way, if the form validation fails, then you are showing the form view file again. this all happens in your controller. also if you use codeigniter form helper, and form validation, it makes showing the error messages, etc, much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to keep the original URL. Was I clear about my problem?

Comment: I understand, but when I submit the form the `action` calls a different method than the method to render the view. I made this because there are two different type for user, and I wanted to avoid repeating any code, but now it led me to this problem.

Comment: yeah its hard to diagnosis without seeing all your code. in general get things working - then refactor. but i'm still going to encourage you not to pass the ID in the URL.

Comment: I had a method for redirecting the page which I used in case the validations fail. Sadly the URL remain the same as the path for the `edit` method, but oddly, even if I alter the `id`, the information remain the same.

Comment: do not redirect if the form validation fails. just call up a method to show the form again. you will still be in the same session and you will be able to use codeigniter form validation to easily show the form validation error messages, the values they entered in the form, etc etc.

Comment: The messages are shown, the problem is the page URL that is changed according to the action from the form, you know? The URL to print the form is one, but the action the perform the add or edit action is different, and when showing errors, the URL changes to the action method.